# Newline In File

Tags: php, newline

I got this problem...
I have a php script named getdata.php

```
 <?php

    $filename = "data";
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $data = explode("\n", $data);

    print_r($data);
?>
```

And a data file

```
name admin\nname guest
```

When I run the php code I just get:

```
Array ( [0] => name admin\nname guest )
```

I want the output is

```
Array ( [0] => name admin [1] => name guest )
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
    $data = explode("\n", $data);
```

to

```
    $data = explode("\\n", $data);
```

The issue is that in the data file `\n` is a string of 2 characters `\` and `n`, but in your `explode` invocation it is a single control character `\n`. By changing this to `\\n` it's now  the same 2 characters as the data

Answer (score 0):

why not trying to use `<br>` instead

```
<?php

    $filename = "data";
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $data = explode("<br>", $data);

    print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments please find my Updated

Try with '\n\n'

```
<?php

    $filename = "data";
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $pieces = explode('\n\n', $data);

    echo $pieces[0]; // name admin
    echo $pieces[1]; // name guest
?>
```

Comment: His `\n` is a string, not an actual newline. He either needs `'\n'` (single quotes) or `"\\n"` to escape the slash.